# Linear regression function in R with conditions for the coefficients

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, least-squares

I've searched and searched without finding an answer, although I think it's not that hard what I want R to do... I'm sorry for spelling mistakes, I'm not a native speaker ;)

I have a few (x,y)-data points all between 0 and 1, e.g. (0,0),(0.2,0.05),(0.4,0.15),(0.6,0.3),(0.8,0.6),(1,1).

I want R to compute a regression function (with least squares method) y=a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x to fit those data points in the interval [0,1].
(So I want it to be a polynomial of degree 3, but with d=0 because it should always go threw the point (0,0), which can easily be forced by adding the -1 in the lm-formula.)

Additionally, I want c to be 1-a-b, because I need f(1) = 1.

```
# regression model: y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx = ax^3 + bx^2 + (1-a-b)x
output <- lm(I(yValues) ~ I(xValues^3) + I(xValues^2) + I(xValues) -1) 

# coefficients:
d1 <- summary(output)$coefficients[1] 
d2 <- summary(output)$coefficients[2] 
d3 <- summary(output)$coefficients[3]
```

does what I want, but, of course, without forcing the condition c=1-a-b. I have not found any possibility to define the regression model the way I want. 
I know Maple can do it, e.g. with 
`reg1 := x --> LeastSquares(xValues, yValues, x, curve = c*x^3+d*x^2+(1-c-d)*x)`, 
but how to define such a condition to R?

I would appreciate any helpful answers!
Thank you very much!

Comment: So, you want basically a linear model with constraints on the parameters. Two relevant posts are: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21565/how-do-i-fit-a-constrained-regression-in-r-so-that-coefficients-total-1 http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/linear-model-with-constraints . Moreover, package `glmc` seems to do that in a simple way

Comment: Thanks. I decided to do it with the "trick" `output <- lm(I(yWerte-xWerte) ~ I(xWerte^3-xWerte) + I(xWerte^2-xWerte)-1) `, so calculate the regression for Y-X =a (X^2-X) + b(X^2-X). The other solutions proposed where too complicated for me (and especially for the people who are supposed to understand what happens in the regression *g*)